# How to map key of first array to key-value of second array php

Tags: php, associative-array

I have 2 arrays
**Array 1**

```
[display_options_checkbox] => Array
        (
            [body] => body
            [nid] => nid
            [title] => 0
            [created] => 0
            [changed] => 0
        )
```

and **Array 2:**

```
[midsvn] => Array
(
[mid_radio_body] => Desc
    [mid_radio_nid] => Assc
    [mid_radio_title] => Assc
    [mid_radio_created] => Assc
    [mid_radio_changed] => Assc
)
```

**How to map the keys of `display_options_checkbox` to the key value of of *midsvn* array?**

For example:
Can I get this kind of array structure?

```
Array(
[body] => array(
[mid_radio_body] => Desc
)
[nid] => array(
[mid_radio_nid] => Assc
)
```

and so on..

or

```
Array(
[body] => Desc,
[nid] => Assc,
[title] => Assc,
[created] => Assc,
[changed] => Assc
)
```

Comment: You'd have to have something that connects them, a ID would be most common for a loop or similar, otherwise you could do something simple as `$display_options_checkbox['body'] = $midsvn['mid_radio_body'];`

Comment: The **order** will be same all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first result:

```
$result = array();
foreach (array_keys($array1['display_options_checkbox']) as $key) {
    $result[$key] = array('mid_radio_' . $key => $array2['midsvn']['mid_radio_' . $key]);
}
```

For the second result:

```
$result = array();
foreach (array_keys($array1['display_options_checkbox']) as $key) {
    $result[$key] = $array2['midsvn']['mid_radio_' . $key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array1 as $key1 => $value1){
    if(array_key_exists($key1,$array2)){
        /* do your mapping stuff here */
    }
}
```